# Can I use Jquery UI datepicker to change format of a keyboard-entered date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, keyboard, datepicker

The Norwegian date format is dd.mm.yyyy. I've changed the datepicker dateformat to this, no problem. However, if a user decides to enter a date by keyboard, they might for instance enter 3.4.12, or even just 3.4. I would like the datepicker to format the dates correctly on blur, even if the date was entered by keyboard and not by choosing from the datepicker. I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
$('.dp').datepicker({
   onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      $(this).val(dateText)
   }
})
```

Nothing happens to the input, because the dateText returned is identical to the entered value.

Comment: Doesn't the datepicker work if the complete date is typed in? Seemed to work in my tests. The issue seems to be partial dates like 3.4. Is that right?

Comment: I can't get it to work with a full date like 3.4.2012 either (The output should be 03.04.2012). Did you test using my code?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/jbXNP/) should get you going in the right direction. It's been tested in Chrome and works as you expect.

Comment: I can see it's working in Chrome. In FF, however, it doesn't work at all. But anyway, writing a function to manipulate dateText I can do. I was just wondering if .datepicker had the functionality built-in. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: The link to jsfiddle in this answer now results in a 404.